# How can I improve my domain's DNS record?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, spf

What DNS information can I add or change to improve the DNS record for my domain name ([tjrobinson.net](http://tjrobinson.net/))? I use it to host a basic website and for my email. [ZoneEdit](http://www.zoneedit.com/) host my DNS records.

**Ideas so far**

- Set up SPF record
- Add DomainKeys support
- Add Sender-ID support
- Fix the warnings listed by [ZoneCheck](http://www.zonecheck.fr/demo/)
- Fix the errors listed by [DNSQueries](http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/domain_check.php)

Comment: "Improve"?  What, are you competing for some sort of prize?  What is *actually* wrong with your zone?

Comment: Well there are the above DNS check sites giving errors and warnings - what's wrong with investigating and fixing these? What's wrong with improvement?

Comment: Cost/benefit, unintended consequences, and having better things to do with limited time all immediately come to mind.

Comment: I suggest adding some bling to your website. http://bit.ly/3vJyu9

Comment: @duffbeer703 It certainly needs it :)

Comment: @womble Fair and valid points, but reducing the likelihood of emails from my domain being marked as spam is worth the time/risk for me. Maybe the other apparent problems don't need fixing, but I don't see the harm in investigating, assuming I have the time to do so.

Comment: While you're fixing things, you could validate your html: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

Well, many choices.  If you think SPF helps, go for it.  DomainKeys and SPF are all origin controlled, though, so it won't result in less spam, it will just help prevent spammers from sending mail impersonating your domain.

If you are getting warnings from something, what are they?  Fixing ones caused by queries is probably a good thing, but many tools artificially warn about things that the tool author thought important, but in reality are not so critical.

Also consider DNSSEC, and adding your KSK to http://dlv.isc.org/